# Send messages from server to iPad without internet

Tags: ios, ios6, ios7

I need to implement an iOS app, which needs to receive notifications from the server. The problem is this will run in a LAN without internet connection. So I don't think I'll be able to use Apple push notifications.
And also I don't think I can run a background process to listen to the server continuously (as I understood apple doesn't allow that).
So what is the best way to implement this?

Comment: Is this a private enterprise app? Is power usage a concern?

Comment: Yes. this will be a internal app, but later client might want to put it in app store. The app will run at least for about 4 hours continuously and a maximum of 8 hours a day. So battery shouldn't go dead during 4 hours. Good if it can stay for 8 hours.

Comment: Do you already have a way of gathering the information that is in the server? Are you using a timeline inside the server, so that you could something like NSDate to find when the next "call" is to be made?

Comment: This is not called on time based. We'll have another app (lets say Java) running on the server. There when a user click some button I need to send a notification to the iPad. So it is user based and we don't know when we need to send the notifications

Answer (score 3):

If this is for private usage, because this wouldn't be allowed on the app store, you can run a silent audio track to keep the app alive in the background. Then you can check in with the server and display notification to the user (as local notifications, not push notifications).

---

For you future / wider distribution, you probably don't want to go with the public app store. Take a look at the [B2B](https://developer.apple.com/programs/volume/b2b/) options available.

Comment: Thanks, that is one option. But our client mentioned about adding it to app store at a later stage, if that comes as a requirement, would I be able to do this? If I implement that way will the App Store reject the app because of the background processing?

Comment: Would it be a public release, or a sale to other businesses who would run privately? If public, yes, the app will most likely get rejected (and so it should be).

Comment: @Madhu if it goes into the app store at a later date couldn't you just remove the background method that `Wain` has recommended and introduce push notifications?

Comment: @Wain, its like this, we a software company develop this app for our client. They have another set of clients. Our client sell this to their clients. So the employees of those clients' are the end users. They'll run it privately in their companies  in their LANs separately. (My client is planing to put it in App Store mainly because they want to sell it to many of their clients - if there's better way he can distribute it to his clients he will not need to put on App Store. I'm searching about that now).

Comment: @Popeye Even if we put this on App Store, when running the app there won't be any internet. So we won't be able to use push notifications.

Comment: Thanks Wain. It seems B2B is the suitable distribution method for my scenario. It seems this also has to go through a Review Process(May be the same as Appstore submission review). According to visualication's answer it looks like that we can run background tasks from iOS 7 and hope they do not reject them after iOS 7. But will have to see how the battery life goes.

Answer (score 0):

since ios 7 you can use background tasks for downloading and network connections. its now official supported from apple. check out this tutorials:

[NSURLSession Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/51127/nsurlsession-tutorial)

[iOS 7 SDK: Background Transfer Service](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-7-sdk-background-transfer-service/)

Comment: I followed these tutorials and implemented the background transfer to run in the background continuously, by calling download one after the other. It seems to run in the background now. But the issues is when I run it in foreground, the transfer happen continuously. But when it moves to background, the transfer get slow, I can see around 1 minute gap between the requests. Not sure why it happens.